# How to get output from enum using user input? C#

Tags: enums

I wrote this code to ask user for inputting one of the values in the enumeration but I don't know how to connect the enumeration values to the user input. Please help.

Thank you!

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, please enter the numerical value corresponding to your transportation mode.Car = 10 / Bus = 20 / Bicycle = 5 / Cab = 7.");
            int TransportationModeInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        public enum TransporationMode
        {
            Car = 10,
            Bus = 20,
            Bicycle = 5,
            Cab = 7
        }

        int ModeCar = (int)TransporationMode.Car;
        int ModeBus = (int)TransporationMode.Bus;
        int ModeBicycle = (int)TransporationMode.Bicycle;
        int ModeCab = (int)TransporationMode.Cab;



  }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(TransporationMode)TransportationModeInput** It Auto Casting to enum

```
public enum TransporationMode
{
    Car = 10,
    Bus = 20,
    Bicycle = 5,
    Cab = 7
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, please enter the numerical value corresponding to your transportation mode.Car = 10 / Bus = 20 / Bicycle = 5 / Cab = 7.");
        int TransportationModeInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Answer:" + ((TransporationMode)TransportationModeInput).ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I tried it but the answer is not read in the terminal, how can I fix that please? i